# How tuple comparision algorithm works in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have executed following tuple cmp(), but unable to understand the cmp algorithm

a) When both tuple are equal , same data type , same value

```
>>> t=(1,2)
>>> t1=(1,2)
>>> print cmp(t,t1)
0
```

b) when 2nd value is bigger

```
>>> t=(1,2)
>>> t1=(2,2)
>>> print cmp(t,t1)
-1
```

c) and so on ....

```
>>> t=(1,2)
>>> t1=('a',2)
>>> print cmp(t,t1)
-1

>>> t=(1,2)
>>> t1=('a',2)
>>> print cmp(t1,t)
1


>>> t=(1,2)
>>> t1=(1,2,3)
>>> print cmp(t,t1)
-1
```

Comment: `(1)` is just `1`. One element tuple looks like `(1,)`.

Comment: For readability it does not help that you change the order of `t` and `t1` declarations all the time..

Comment: i have updated the question and order..hope it makes things clear

Answer (score 0):

You don't have tuples in most places. It is the **comma operator** that makes an object a tuple, using just `(...)` only groups an expression:

```
>>> (1)
1
>>> 1,
(1,)
>>> type((1))
<type 'int'>
>>> type((1,))
<type 'tuple'>
```

As such, all your samples are incorrect, in all you have at least one object that is not a tuple.

Your comparisons are therefor *mostly* between integers, and integers and strings. Numbers (including integers) always sort before other objects in Python 2. In Python 3, comparing different non-numeric types is an error.

**Actual** tuple comparison compare the contents in lexicographical order; applying `cmp()` to each paired up value in the tuple in turn until `cmp()` returns something other than `0`:

```
>>> a = 1, 2
>>> b = 1, 3  # b is 'larger' because 3 > 2
>>> cmp(a, b)
-1
>>> b = 1, 2  # now equal across all values
>>> cmp(a, b)
0
```

Comment: Thanks Martijn, I will update my question .

Comment: @user3812837: and what remains is a duplicate question, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behaviour there are 3 scenarios:

```
cmp() returns -1 if x < y
cmp() returns 0 if x == y
cmp() returns 1 if x > y
```

In your last scenarios

```
>>> t1=(2)
>>> t=(3)
>>> print cmp(t,t1)
1
```

They are both integers, a tuple consists of at least one comma. `(1,)` or `(1,2)` etc. Since 3 is bigger than 2 it returns 1

```
>>> t=(3)
>>> t1=('a')
>>> print cmp(t,t1)
-1
```

Integer and character, in this case a has a bigger asciii value so -1

```
>>> t1=(2)
>>> t=(2,3)
>>> print cmp(t,t1)
1
```

The tuple is bigger than the int so 1

```
>>> t=('a')
>>> t1=(3)
>>> print cmp(t,t1)
1
```

"a" bigger than 3 so 1, opposite of the other one

```
>>> t=(2)
>>> t1=(3,2)
>>> print cmp(t,t1)
-1
```

2 is just an integer.

Comment: The OP expected to compare *tuples* and is asking why the outcomes are unexpected *because they expected to compare tuples*.

Comment: Not done yet with answer give me some time...

Comment: If you are going to start with a partial answer, at least give a **correct** partial answer. This part doesn't answer the question, the OP clearly knows how `cmp()` works.

Comment: Yes yes you are right, but typing on a phone is not always handy... I edited my answer...

Comment: There are still errors in your answer however. *a tuple consists of at least 2 elements* is absolutely not true, because `1,` is a tuple with one element.

Comment: It depends how you see it, (1,empty) but ok, updated my answer. Thanks for the remarks anyways.

Comment: No, there is no `(1, empty)`. Tuples are created by the `,` comma operator. The parentheses are optional, unless the context has assigned another meaning to the comma (such as in a method call) or you want to create a tuple of tuples. `(1,)` is not a tuple with two elements, the second one empty, it is a tuple with one element, grouped in parentheses. See https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#parenthesized-forms, https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#expression-lists and https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences

Comment: ok thanks! learned something new today :D

Comment: cmp() returns -1 if x < y
cmp() returns 0 if x == y
cmp() returns 1 if x > y; explains most of the doubt ....only query left is what happens if the length of tuple does doesn't match ?